# searching items in listbox using uppercase and lowercase

Tags: c#, search, visual-studio-2008, textbox, listbox

Good Day, I made a listbox that contains a list of items that I can search it in the textbox and transfer it in the other listbox. I made this code and it worked.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();

    for (i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
        }
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        sb.Append(item.ToString());
        sb.Append(" ");
    }
    possibleresult rslt = new possibleresult();
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
    foreach (int i in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
    {
        listBox2.Visible = true;
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    }      
}
```

And now I want to search an item that can read either small letters or big letters.
I research some of codes using UpperCase and LowerCase but honestly speaking i don't know how to do it.
can you help me sir with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :** You can convert both values into either UPPERCASE or lowercase and then perform the comparison.

Try This:

```
listBox1.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())
```

OR

```
listBox1.Items[i].ToString().ToUpper().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpper())
```

Comment: Tnx sir Now it works..
I thought I have to make a class for an Upper or Lower case.
thats what I have read in my research

Comment: @SpideyEudzAragon: you are welcome :), i'm Glad tobe help of you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();

            for (i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (string.Equals(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), textBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to transfer all items to Lower Case or Upper Case - Worked 100%

For Lower Case

```
For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item.ToString.ToLower)
        Next
```

For Upper Case

```
For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item.ToString.ToUpper)
        Next
```